# Need to create a date based of this "2013-10-25T00:00:00" ? Getting errors (Oracle, pl/sql)

Tags: date, datetime, plsql

I am trying to convert this into a date, but everything I have tried has failed so far, I keep getting the following error in the following code

ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

```
 TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(REPLACE(ENRL_DT,'T', ' '), 'YYYY-Mm-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'DD/MM/YY') AS ENRL_Date
```

I also used this piece of code earlier

```
to_timestamp(enrl_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"') as enrol_date,
```

I still get the same error, I tried using a where clause at the end to exclude the null values from the field but that didn't work either

```
     Where enrl_dt is not null
```

Any ideas, this a lot of records so going through them individually would be a nightmare.

Anyway I can turn this into a date, or date with timestamp either would be great. Please let me know.

Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Your conversion works fine for me with `'2013-10-25T00:00:00'` and null values. There must be some data that violates the rules given in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(REPLACE('2013-10-25T00:00:00','T', ' '), 'YYYY-Mm-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'DD/MM/YY') AS ENRL_Date FROM DUAL;
```

ENRL_Date

```
25/10/13
```

I am using 11g oracle.It work for me.
It will be help you.